# @Scheduled annotationed method starts in wrong time

Tags: java, annotations, schedule

I have method annotaded with `@Scheduled("cron = 0 3 * * * *")` but it runs not in 3am each day but each hour. What`s wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are totally 6 fields in cron expression in this order - second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day(s) of week. You have configured only the second and minute.so, it will every hour in the third minute.

Cron should be `0 0 3 * * *`

Now, it will run 3:00:00 AM everyday in the morning

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need 0 0 3 ... in your expression instead of 
0 3 ..

EDIT
Specifically 0 0 3 1/1 * ? *